# Issue counting using conditional datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm trying to count all my policies that are'n expired >= that today

```
  date_end >= TODAY
```

Here is my table

```
|policies|
  |id|  |num|    |date_ini|  |date_end|
   1    12484    2013-04-01   2014-05-01
   2    41511    2012-04-01   2013-05-01
   3    14441    2013-05-01   2014-06-01
```

There are 2 values that aren't expired

Here is my controller

```
 @policies =Policy.count(:conditions =>['date_end >= Date.now'])
```

I tried

```
 @policies =Policy.count(:conditions =>['date_end >= Date.today'])
```

And also

```
 @policies =Policy.count(:conditions =>['date_end >= curtime()'])
```

Please somebody can help me?

I will really appreciate help

Comment: NOTE: do NOT use `Date.today` use `Date.current` - see http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/ and http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails#cheat_sheet

Comment: also consider using rails 3+ style of querying `Policy.where("date_end >= ?", Date.current).count`, the `conditions` style is for rails 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working because `Date.today` is inside a String, so it isn't being evaluated as an actual Date. You probably also want to use `Date.current` instead, to take the configured time zone into account.

Try this instead:

```
@policies = Policy.count( :conditions => ['date_end >= ?', Date.current] )
```

Comment: change to `Date.current`; `Date.today` can return the wrong day at certain times of the day, depending on the timezone

Answer (score 1):

If `date_end` is stored as a `DATE` type of attribute, you can do this:

```
Policy.where("date_end >= ?", Date.today).count
```

or if it's stored as a string, just convert the Date.today to a string:

```
Policy.where("date_end >= ?", Date.today.to_s).count
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call out Date.today, you are returning the format "Fri, 15 Nov 2013" which will not compare to "2014-04-02".  To get them in the same format, use

`Date.today.to_s`